# Convert database values to JSON, without column names

Tags: php, ajax, json, laravel

I'm trying to get a list of categories and return them as JSON for an AJAX call, but Laravel is including column names too, which I don't need.

```
$categories = Category::where('parent', '=', '0')->select('name')->get();
return response()->json($categories);
```

This way I get

```
[{"column_name", "value"}]
```

And I want

```
{"value1", "value2"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you are doing in your `json()` method, but neither are valid json. Are you sure you want to do it like this?

Comment: Yeah that's not the JSON I get, I wrote it by hand and it seems I got it wrong. I think I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `$arr = json_decode($categories, true)`. Then deal with the array output it gives.

Answer (score 1):

You simply use eloquent's `lists` method

```
$categories = Category::where('parent', '=', '0')->select('name')->lists('name');

return response()->json($categories);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use array_values function to get the values array.

And `{"value1", "value2"}`the format is invalid of Json . Valid format `["value1","value2"]` . If use { } means to Object ,but object must have key=>value.

```
$categories = Category::where('parent', '=', '0')->select('name')->get();
return response()->json(array_values($categories));
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`

Comment: Why? OP's output is not an array, it's a JSON string.

Comment: Get() result can convert to array? Like get()->toArray()?